# Multiple parameters with CompositePresentationEvent<> in Prism

Tags: c#, events, prism

I would like to know how to pass two or more parameters to Prism event aggregator (event class inherits CompositePresentationEvent)?

I know I can create wrapper class like EventArgs and create property for each value I need, but I would rather to pass two distinct parameters.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the event aggregator is only set up to pass a single parameter.  HOWEVER, that parameter *can* be a class or structure.

Here is an example of a "message" I pass with event aggregator, including a callback parameter.

```
public class OpenViewPayload
{
    public string ViewName;
    public object Context;
    public Action callback;
}

[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class OpenViewEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<OpenViewPayload>
{
}
```

Usage:

```
 _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenViewEvent>().Publish(new OpenViewPayload() { ViewName = "CustomerView", Context = _selectedCustomerID, callback= ()=> { /* Close Current View */ } });
```

Comment: It would be wise to make the payload immutable, or a `struct`, or you risk another subscriber fiddling with the payload before you receive it.